# Basic axis malfuction in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, axis, scaling

When plotting using matplotlib, I ran into an interesting issue where the y axis is scaled by a very inconvenient quantity. Here's a MWE that demonstrates the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = np.linspace(0.5,2,2**10)
a =  (0.696*l**2)/(l**2 - 9896.2e-9**2)

plt.plot(l,a)
plt.show()
```

When I run this, I get a figure that looks like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBgPh.png)

The y-axis clearly is scaled by a silly quantity even though the y data are all between 1 and 2.

This is similar to the question:
[Axis numerical offset in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253742/axis-numerical-offset-in-matplotlib)

I'm not satisfied with the answer to this question in that it makes no sense to my why I need to go the the convoluted process of changing axis settings when the data are between 1 and 2 (EDIT: between 0 and 1). Why does this happen? Why does matplotlib use such a bizarre scaling?

Comment: Try `min(a)` and `max(a)`, the y-data is **not** between 1 and 2. Your values are almost constant as you can also see with `plt.ylim(0, 2)`. So I wouldn't call that a 'silly quantity'.

Comment: Ack I copied the wrong code, I was looking at ipython and made a silly mistake. Sorry! Nevertheless, I'm curious as to where the problem comes from. The labelling is still not very useful in any situation. Why does matplotlib do this?

Comment: There is no problem! Everything works as expected. If you want a different ticklabeling, please specify exactly what you want in the question itself.

Comment: It turns out that I was misinterpreting the offset as 1e(-10 + 6.96e-1) as opposed to 1e-10 + 6.96e-1. This made no sense when I looked at the array. Order of operations still works and there is no malfunction. It looks like the a simple way to get scientific notation correctly every time is 
`plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset']=True` and `plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits']= (0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

The data in the plot are all between `0.696000000017` and `0.696000000273`. For such cases it makes sense to use some kind of offset.

If you don't want that, you can use you own formatter:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

l = np.linspace(0.5,2,2**10)
a =  (0.696*l**2)/(l**2 - 9896.2e-9**2)

plt.plot(l,a)
fmt = matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:.12f}")
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]